# Java 8 catch 22 with lambda expressions and effectively final

Tags: java, java-8

I'm playing with Java 8 and hit a basic scenario that illustrates a catch 22 where fixing one compile error causes another compile error. The scenario (which is just an example simplified from something more complex):

```
public static List<String> catch22(List<String> input) {
    List<String> result = null;
    if (input != null) {
      result = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
      input.forEach(e -> result.add(e)); // compile error here
    }

    return result;
}
```

I get a compile error:

> Local variable result defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

If I change the first line to:

```
List<String> result;
```

I get a compile error on the last line:

> The local variable result may not have been initialized

It seems like the only approach here is to pre-initialize my result to an ArrayList, which I don't want to do, or not use lambda expressions. Am I missing any other solution?

Comment: OTOH, the callers of this method won't be happy to check for null every time they need to access the returned list. Do the right thing, and return an empty list instead of returning null.

Comment: You are just transferring the values from `input` to `result`?

Comment: @RohitJain In this simplified fake example, yes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error is coming because your `result` list is not effectively `final` which is a requirement for it's usage in lambda. One option is to declare the variable inside the `if` condition, and `return null;` outside. But I don't think that would be good idea. Your current  method is not doing anything productive. It would make much more sense to return an empty list from it.

Having said that all, I would say, since you are playing with Java 8, use [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) along with streams here:

```
public static List<String> catch22(List<String> input) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(input)
            .orElse(new ArrayList<String>())
            .stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And if you want to return `null`, I'll probably change your method to:

```
public static List<String> catch22(List<String> input) {
    if (input == null) return null;
    return input.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    // Or this. B'coz this is really what your code is doing.
    return new ArrayList<>(input);
}
```

Comment: Good answer - thanks for showing two diff interesting approaches.

Comment: In that first example, even if `input` is passed as non-null, the call to `.orElse` means that the constructor expression (the `new ArrayList`) will always happen.  I don't see any rule that the argument to the function call is allowed to be _not_ evaluated.  So if the runtime optimizer isn't smart enough about `orElse` semantics to skip evaluating its argument, it's going to create an ArrayList with default capacity, and then immediately mark it as garbage.  (Granted, all this is just an example, so this doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 10):

Push the declaration inside the block with input != null. Example:

```
public static List<String> catch22(List<String> input) {
    if (input != null) {
        List<String> result;
        result = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
        input.forEach(e -> result.add(e)); // compile error here
        return result;
    } else {
        return null; // or empty list or something that suits your app
    }
}
```

Comment: result doesn't need to be final. It needs to be *effectively* final.

Answer (score 2):

`forEach(...)` applies an operation on each element of the `Stream`.  You really don't want that, you want a `Stream` "consumer" which produces a single output of `List<String>`.

Fortunately these are considered `Collector`s in the current framework, and `Collectors.toList()` does exactly what you want.

```
List<String> duplicate = input.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, i summarized some general solutions for lambdas expressions modifying method local variables.

Lambdas Expressions are actually anonymous inner classes in a concise form. When we use them in local methods we should take several constraints into consideration:

- lambdas expressions(anonymous inner class) cant modify local variables of surrounding method [link here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiK49LK_LzRAhUjQJoKHZ4ZB9kQFggiMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4732544%2Fwhy-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class&usg=AFQjCNEfjS6-A0XSwf_JCFUKwssoXGDldg&sig2=t9WXo58OT4voMopC0t3wxQ&bvm=bv.144210762,d.bGs) they must be final or in java 8  [effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517916/why-this-inner-class-code-compiles/41518287#41518287)
- Unlike instance variables, local variables do not get default values and if you want to use or return them you must initialize them first

When these two constraints collide (in case of defining a lambdas in a method where lambdas modifies local variable in surrounding method), we get into trouble

solutions:

solution 1: do not modify method local variable in lambdas or use instance variables instead

solution 2: do some tricks, for example copy local variable into another one and pass that to lambdas:

```
public static List<String> catch22(List<String> input) {
 List<String> result = null;
 if (input != null) {
   result = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
   List<String> effectivelyFinalResult = result;
   input.forEach(e -> effectivelyFinalResult.add(e)); 
 }
 return result;
}
```

or limit local variables scope so you dont get into trouble for not initializing them:

```
public static List<String> catch22(List<String> input) {
if (input != null) {
    List<String> result; // result gets its value in the lambdas so it is effectively final
    result = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
    input.forEach(e -> result.add(e));
    return result;
} else {
    return null; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By making the result final and putting the null assignment in the else block you can keep the current structure of your method and 'solve' your catch22.

```
public static List<String> catch22(List<String> input) {
    final List<String> result;
    if (input != null) {
        result = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
        input.forEach(e -> result.add(e));
    } else {
        result = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
public static List<String> catch22(List<String> input) {
List<String> result = null;
if (input != null) {
  result = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
  List<String> effectivelyFinalResult = result;
  input.forEach(e -> effectivelyFinalResult.add(e)); // No compile error here
}

return result;
}
```

to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Its presence prevents the introduction of a new class of multithreading bugs involving local variables.

Local variables in Java have until now been immune to race conditions and visibility problems because they are accessible only to the thread executing the method in which they are declared. But a lambda can be passed from the thread that created it to a different thread, and that immunity would therefore be lost if the lambda, evaluated by the second thread, were given the ability to mutate local variables.

Even the ability to read the value of mutable local variables from a different thread would introduce the necessity for synchronization or the use of volatile in order to avoid reading stale data.